# How can I sort numbers as though they were words?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Ruby's `Array#sort` will, by default, sort numbers like this, in order of their value:

```
[11, 12, 13, 112, 113, 124, 125, 127]
```

I'd like to sort an array of numbers like this, as though they were words being alphabetized:

```
[11, 112, 113, 12, 124, 125, 127, 13]
```

How can I do this? (Ultimately, I want to do this with Hash keys, so if you want to answer that way instead, that's fine.) Also, is there a name for this type of sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>You are all crqzy )))</s> I have a such solution:

```
a.sort_by &:to_s
```

Comment: This is the shortest possible solution. In Ruby 1.9 you can also ue that same method to sort the array in place: a.sort_by!(&:to_s)

Comment: @psycho Note that `sort_by!` is 1.9.2+ only (not present in 1.9.1)

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way is to convert all of the values to strings, then convert them back.

```
a = [11, 12, 13, 112, 113, 124, 125, 127]
a = a.map(&:to_s).sort.map(&:to_i)
p a # => [11, 112, 113, 12, 124, 125, 127, 13]
```

Comment: Ha! Well, that's both simple and clever. :)

Comment: @tokland: My answer came first ;) `sort_by` is definitely gonna be a part of my toolbox in the future, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass in a block](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000244) to sort that accepts two arguments and returns the result of your own custom-defined comparison function. The example should speak for itself, but should you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
a = [11, 112, 113, 12, 124, 125, 127, 13]
new_a = a.sort do |x,y|
  "%{x}" <=> "%{y}"
end
puts new_a
```

A note: I suspect that the reason you're looking for this sort of solution is because the objects you want sorted are not `Integer`s at heart. It might be worthwhile and semantically more pleasing to subclass `Integer`. Although it will obviously make instantiation harder, it feels more correct, at least to me.

Comment: I like this method, too, since it's easy to extend in the future :) +1 As far as performance goes, however, it's probably best to do two conversions total on each element than to convert each to string each time it's compared.

Comment: The difference, in practice, is negligible. I revised our two pieces of code to accomplish more similar results (removed the outputs statements and added a `!` to my method call). For 10k times, I got 2.7s for mine and 2.8s for yours. [See profiler output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KYe766d9).

Comment: You're right that they're not `Integer`s at heart; in fact, I'm really using them like strings, so I don't think it's necessary to subclass `Integer` in my case. But I think that's a good point to raise.

Comment: @Nathan: thanks for the kind words. Most of the credit goes to the Ruby library designers, who made basic performance profiling ludicrously easy. You just add `require 'profile'`. It really brings me back to my PHP days of copypasting `microtime()` all over the place.

Comment: Oh, man, `require 'profile'`. Yet another tool for my toolbox. I think I've learned more from this question than I contributed xD